# Need to copy files into subfolder

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to copy a particular number of files from one folders subdirectory to another folders subdirectory, I have tried with below code but it is not working properly.

```
import os
import shutil
def copy_files_to(src, dest):
    dirList = os.listdir(src)

    for folder in dirList:
        files_in_folder = os.listdir(src + folder)
        for f in files_in_folder:
            source_files = src + folder + '\\' + f

            if not os.path.exists(dest):
                os.mkdir(dest)
                shutil.copy(source_files, dest)

copy_files_to("\\src", "\\dest")
```

please help on this. I want to only copy only 30 files to the destination folder, not all files.

Comment: "It's not working properly" - *what does it do or not do?*

Comment: it copies only one file

Comment: Add some print statements and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The files are just copied when the dest directory doesn't exist, i think you want:

```
if not os.path.exists(dest):
    os.mkdir(dest)
shutil.copy(source_files, dest)
```

Comment: yes, actually I have a root folder you can say "Test" which has 3 sub folders lets say "test1", "test2", "test3", all these 3 folders having 50 files each, so i want to create a directory named "newtest1", "newtest2", "newtest3" and copy only 10 files for each. when i run my code it copies only 1 file.